# How can I compile a MATLAB exe with C#?

Tags: c#, matlab

How can I use/start a MATLAB file, compiled to an exe-file, with C#? I have created a 3D plot in MATLAB, which I want to execute in C#. Is it possible?

This C# code I found:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 

namespace ConsoleApplication2 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            // Create the MATLAB instance 
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); 

            // Change to the directory where the function is located 
            matlab.Execute(@"cd c:\temp\example"); 

            // Define the output 
            object result = null; 

            // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
            matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result, 3.14, 42.0, "world"); 

            // Display result 
            object[] res = result as object[]; 

            Console.WriteLine(res[0]); 
            Console.WriteLine(res[1]); 
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Especially the title of your question makes no sense at all. Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mathworks [website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html) from which you have your example also explains what you have to do to make it work. 
1. Create a MATLAB function, myfunc, in the folder c:\temp\example.

```
function [x,y] = myfunc(a,b,c) 
x = a + b; 
y = sprintf('Hello %s',c);
```

2. Create the C# application.
3. In Microsoft® Visual Studio®, add a reference to your C# project to the MATLAB COM object. From the Project menu, select Add Reference.
4. Select the COM tab in the Add Reference dialog box.
5. Select the MATLAB application.